# online api for text to image conversion

Tags: cloud-service, text-processing

I'm working on a program to create facebook messenger cards for "tips of the day". The tips are often longer than a facebook messenger card would allow, so I'd like to put the text in a .gif or .png and post that. I'm looking for an on-line api that would allow me to send the text and then give me a link to the image. img4me.com is pretty close, but you can't control the size of the output image and it tends to cut off the last line or two. Any other suggestions? TIA.

Comment: can you add 2 or 3 blank lines at end of message?  Is these get cut off so what.

Comment: @john, It seems to strip blanks. I added about 100 blanks with a ! at the end. That seemed to solve the problem. But the real problem was I couldn't create the image in the format facebook wanted 500x250 px, so the image was unreadable when it posted to facebook.